# Incomplete OpenCV documentation

Tags: opencv, convolution

I am trying to perform 2D convolutions with OpenCV using the HAL functions.

I understand that I can perform this by instantiating a Filter2D object by means of the function

```
cv::hal::Filter2D::create(uchar *kernel_data, size_t kernel_step, int kernel_type, int kernel_width, int kernel_height, int max_width, int max_height, int stype, int dtype, int borderType, double delta, int anchor_x, int anchor_y, bool isSubmatrix, bool isInplace);
```

then use the function

```
cv::hal::Filter2D::apply(...);
```

The `create` function takes 15 arguments. So far, I haven't found any documentation about them, other than the argument names and types. This is far from being sufficient.

Where can I get better information ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only doc about `hall::filter2d` i was able to find is [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/hal_replacement.hpp). It's not the exact `Filter2D` but i think the param brief explanation might help you a bit.

```
/**
   @brief hal_filterInit
   @param context double pointer to user-defined context
   @param kernel_data pointer to kernel data
   @param kernel_step kernel step
   @param kernel_type kernel type (CV_8U, ...)
   @param kernel_width kernel width
   @param kernel_height kernel height
   @param max_width max possible image width, can be used to allocate working buffers
   @param max_height max possible image height
   @param src_type source image type
   @param dst_type destination image type
   @param borderType border processing mode (CV_HAL_BORDER_REFLECT, ...)
   @param delta added to pixel values
   @param anchor_x relative X position of center point within the kernel
   @param anchor_y relative Y position of center point within the kernel
   @param allowSubmatrix indicates whether the submatrices will be allowed as source image
   @param allowInplace indicates whether the inplace operation will be possible
   @sa cv::filter2D, cv::hal::Filter2D
 */
inline int hal_ni_filterInit(cvhalFilter2D **context, uchar *kernel_data, size_t kernel_step, int kernel_type, int kernel_width, int kernel_height, int max_width, int max_height, int src_type, int dst_type, int borderType, double delta, int anchor_x, int anchor_y, bool allowSubmatrix, bool allowInplace) { return CV_HAL_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED; }
```

Comment: This is terse, but helpful. Thanks !